# Put data in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var mypafgfr = [];
mypafgfr[0] = "tt";
mypafgfr[1] = "tt";
mypafgfr[2] = "tt";
var outputdata = {};

function ls() {
    console.log(mypafgfr[0]); {
        var gg = {};
        gg["n"] = mypafgfr[0];
        gg["image1"] = mypafgfr[1];
        gg["image2"] = mypafgfr[2];
        outputdata["folder"] = gg;
    }
    console.log(outputdata);
}

ls();

mypafgfr[0] = "yy";
mypafgfr[1] = "yy";
mypafgfr[2] = "yy";

ls();
```

In console I'm expect to see

```
Object { n="tt",  image1="tt",  image2="tt"}
Object { n="yy",  image1="yy",  image2="yy"}
```

but I got

```
Object { n="yy",  image1="yy",  image2="yy"}
Object { n="yy",  image1="yy",  image2="yy"}
```

What I'm doing wrong? How it happen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is because `console.log()` prints the reference of the object.

You could you `console.dir()` instead to see how the object looks at call time.

One more fallback you can use is to use `JSON.stringify()` at the time of logging it, which does not point to the reference.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(outputdata));
```